# LOOP instruction fails to loop even though (--cx != 0)

Tags: debugging, assembly, masm, x86-16, code-view

I'm implementing a multiplication algorithm for school, so please no help with the algorithm. I'm using *C* subroutine conventions, so I don't need to push *CX*, and the result is returned in *DX:AX* . I'm using `codeview` to do the debugging.

At the *LOOP* line, *CX* is seen to be 16:

[image]

After stepping with <kbd>F10</kbd>, I believe it should put me back at the `shiftR` label. What happens is that *CX* becomes 0, and I continue to exit the subroutine as is seen in this screenshot:

[image]

As well, you can see that the Carry and Overflow flags are set after stepping! I didn't think *LOOP* could do that? What gives? What am I overlooking?

Comment: What if you use F8 instead of F10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED: I jumped the gun. As [David Wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189500/david-wohlferd) mentioned, <kbd>F8</kbd> is `step` and <kbd>F10</kbd> is `next` using *GDB* terminology.